# Travelling to England with a criminal record

Tags: england

So, 3 years ago I was convicted with a simple assault/domestic with a 3 year filing which means it will be completely off my record in november of this year.  Im planning on going to england to visit for 2 weeks in may and was wondering if that was going to be a problem or if im going to be fine.  I was never imprisoned for it but i did have to take like 3 months of a batterers intervention program, but like i said that was 3 years ago.  Is this going to be a problem? and if you answer can you post a source? ive been looking on government websites and couldnt find anything that pertained to my situation.

Comment: agree duplicate but here is your source https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules.... click on APPENDIX V: Immigration Rules for visitors and you will find the rules in there